# How to retrieve all fields from a swing class in a second class?

Tags: java, swing

I'm not really sure how to go about this and I don't think I'm looking in the right direction.

I have a swing form that contains quite a large number of fields and I want to save these fields in a secondary Save class when the user presses the Save button.

Is there a way I can pass the entire contents of the Swing form to the Save Class?

```
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            SaveMap.MapSave(???);
        }
    });
```

Then:

```
public class SaveMap {  
    public static boolean MapSave(???) {
      // save stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you must extract the text form the fields yourself. Now if your fields are accessible via a Map or an ArrayList, you could possibly use a for loop to help you with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily.  It also depends on what you are trying to save.

Difference controls will provide different data.

Basically, I would create some kind of "builder" that could that could the "name" of the field and either the control itself or it's value...

```
Savable savable = new SaveBuilder.add("userName", userNameField).add("password", passwordField);
SaveMap.MapSave(savable);
```

This has the benifit of allowing to extract the information you need in the way you need it...

or

```
Savable savable = new SaveBuilder.add("userName", userNameField.getText()).add("password", passwordField.getPassword());
SaveMap.MapSave(savable);
```

Obviously, the `SaveMap` would need to be able to extract the property names and values.